# Type '___' has no member 'array'

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am working on this quote app, and I keep running into two errors that just don't want to cooperate with me. It says "Type 'businessQuote' has no member ('array'/'dict')". In the following screen shot, you will see the error on the line. The whole point is to get the app to show a random quote in the text fields provided. Could you please help me? Thank you in advance.

[Code with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFmJt.png)

My goal is to get "ImportList" to work

['ImportList' Swift file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KEGG.png)

If there is another question like this that I have overlooked, I would appreciate it if you could link me to it. But I just really need an answer. Thank you again.

Here's the code with the error:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Social

class businessQuote: UIViewController {

//============================//
//********** Outlets *********//
//============================//

let utility = Utility()
@IBOutlet weak var quoteDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var authorDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var quoteBackground: UIImageView! //GET BACK TO THIS

//============================//
//********** General *********//
//============================//

let date = NSDate()
var Author: String = ""
var Quote: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Checks if time is greater then 3pm to change background
    let currentTime = utility.currentTime()
    if (currentTime >= 15 ) {
        quoteBackground.image = UIImage(named: "quote_background.png")
    } else {
        quoteBackground.image = UIImage(named:"morning_quote_background.png")
    }
}

//============================//
//********* New Quote ********//
//============================//

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    // Generates Random Number
    func randomNumber(arrayLength: Int) -> Int {
        let unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(arrayLength)
        let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
        let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)


        return randomNumber
    }

    // Importing Quotes plist File
    let businessQuotes = ImportList(FileName: "BusinessList")

    // Selects Quote
    let chosenQuote: String = businessQuote.array[randomNumber(businessQuote
        .count())] as! String
    let chosenAuthor = businessQuote.dict[chosenQuote]! as String

    // Assigns Quote & Author to IBOutlet
    Author = chosenAuthor
    Quote = chosenQuote

    quoteDisplay.text = Quote
    authorDisplay.text = Author.uppercaseString
```

}

}

This is the code with the 'array' and 'dict'

```
import Foundation

struct ImportList {
let path: String

init(FileName: String) {
    self.path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(FileName)", ofType: "plist")!
}

var dict: Dictionary<String, String> {
    return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)! as! Dictionary
}

var array: Array<AnyObject> {
    return [String](arrayLiteral: String(dict.keys) { $0 as AnyObject as! String })
}

func count() -> Int {
    return array.count
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should post the code with your question instead of a link to a picture

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared variable **businessQuotes** as:

```
// Importing Quotes plist File
let businessQuotes = ImportList(FileName: "BusinessList")
```

But using **businessQuote** instead, see you are missing "s" at the end. Spelling mistake. Following lines should be:

```
// Selects Quote
let chosenQuote: String = businessQuotes.array[randomNumber(businessQuotes
    .count())] as! String
let chosenAuthor = businessQuotes.dict[chosenQuote]! as String
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel so dumb for not seeing that.